# Impact of not upgrading Facebook Unity SDK

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

We have a unity mobile game that utilises the Facebook Unity SDK. On the Facebook admin page for the app, we see this message:

"Your Facebook SDK for iOS is out of date and missing important iOS 11 fixes that make it easier for people to log into your app"

We are unable to upgrade to the latest version of the Unity Facebook SDK because we are on an old version of Unity (5.3.4p4) and the most recent version of the Facebook SDK requires a minimum unity version of 5.4

- Does anyone know what the impact of not upgrading is?
- Will it cause any massive issues for us?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider upgrade your project to use their latest sdk. Not only Facebook SDK, any SDKs that you use that require update you should update them (but don't directly upgrade to the latest sdk version because it might be broken in some ways [from my experience with Facebook and Google-play SDK]).

The impact of not upgrading is that when their sdks getting more and more updates, they will make the older version sdks to be deprecated and then they'll stop supporting them which mean you won't be able to use their APIs/Features from the old version sdk you're using anymore (if your game heavily relies on their APIs/Features then yes that is super not good)

Friendly reminder: "Don't forget to backup first if you decide to upgrade" :)

Comment: Hi Visal,

Thank you for your input. 

I understand the general benefits of updating SDKs. I was hoping to receive specific feedback that elaborates on the warning message above because it would allow me to make a business case to the executive team explaining why we'd need to spend time and effort upgrading our version of unity and subsequently of the Facebook (and other) SDKs. Without a detailed explanation of the risk involved in not upgrading, it would be a hard sell.

Does anyone know of a way I can directly reach out to the FB team to ask about this?